# Does the United States have requirements or certifications to be classified as an "Exotic Animal Veterinarian"?

Tags: exotic-pets, united-states, veterinarian, certificate

An answer from [How can I gauge a vet's experience with reptiles?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2190) mentions [The Association of Exotic Mammal Veterinarians](http://www.aemv.org/index.cfm), which as best I can tell is a membership organization, not a certifying organization.  They have some great goals, and I see that one of my favorite rabbit vets is a listed member, but a second, very good, rabbit vet is not.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_animal_veterinarian), interest in treating exotic pets is the first criteria; additional training and certifications are secondary.

Is there any official certification I should be looking when evaluating a potential exotics vet?  If so, what level of competence does it imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your specific case is no. The longer answer is that there are board certified veterinary specialists, covering a rather wide swath of specialties, but not the specific one you mentioned (unless you're counting zoo and wildlife animals as a reasonable proximity).

You can find a [list of recognized veterinary specialties](http://www.vetcontact.com/en/vet.php?k=91) and their designations for Europe and the United States on VetContact.